# Ruby on Rails how can add functionality to devise's sign up create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In devise, when the user enters create on the sign up page, i want to switch the member bool to true in the model.

So when create is called,before saving I want to turn the bool to true but since devise doesn't have any controller how can i do that. I cant extend the devise's registration controller since that wouldn't help me in modifying the actual create action to include the code i want. How can i do that?

Comment: You can generate the controllers to add in functionality like this.  https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers.  This blog post may help too, https://chelseatroy.com/2019/04/08/modifying-authentication-behavior-in-devise/ .

Comment: @RockwellRice Thanks for that. I had already generated the devise model User and the views too. Now i generated the controllers `rails g devise:controllers user` would devise know that the users controllers and the model User are linked?

Comment: Did you read the resources?  Did you search for that answer already?  I think you do need to update your `routes.rb` file I believe when generating the controllers, but you should have very little trouble finding examples of that online through a google search.

Comment: You could also do this logic in model callbacks

Answer (score 0):

According to devise documentation, you can generate custom controllers by doing `rails g devise:controllers users`. Then, it will generate some files like `users/sessions_controller.rb` with commented methods in it:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end
  ...
end
```

You can uncomment the methods you need and add your custom code after `super` (otherwise it won't work).
This should do the trick, assuming that you have generated the `User` model with devise's generator (`rails g devise User`)